# How to enable XDebug in VSCode with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, xdebug

I have followed multiple guides, but it seems none of them provide correct solution and most of them are outdated. XDebug is not working.

Environment: Ubuntu 22.04, PHP 8.1, Laravel 10.

I have working laravel installation, that I develop with:

```
php artisan serve
```

I've installed XDebug PHP extension:

```
sudo apt install php-xdebug
```

Configuration file seems to be at `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini`.

I have installed [XDebug VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug) and I have created `launch.json` with default content in VSCode.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003
    },
  ]
}
```

What changes I need to make changes to `launch.json` or `xdebug.ini` to enable XDebug "step debugging"?

**Edit:** Xdebug started working after I set `xdebug.mode = debug` and `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` in `xdebug.ini`.

After changes my `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` content was:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the debugger in VS Code - press F5. Then make sure you have Xdebug helper Browser extension installed, activate it and reload your Laravel page.

If that does not work, add a `xdebug_info();` to the top of your index.php or other PHP file you can load via browser and see if there are any errors, or if the Xdebug debugger is activated.

Alternatively to the Browser extension, you could put `xdebug.start_with_request=1` in your `xdebug.ini`.

It could also be you are missing `xdebug.mode=debug` in your `xdebug.ini`.

If that does not work post you xdebug.ini and the output of `xdebug_info()` here for further help.

There are also other ways how to make it work but these conditions need to be satisfied:

- VS Code is listening on Xdebug port (usually 9003)
- PHP has Xdebug loaded
- PHP has xdebug.mode=debug - either via .ini or XDEBUG_MODE env
- PHP knows to start debugging (Browser extension or `xdebug.start_with_request=1`)
- PHP can connect to VS Code (usually not a problem when everything is on localhost without Docker)

Comment: Thx. I added `xdebug.mode = debug` and `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` to xdebug.ini and xdebug started working.